# How to save the state of my activity after closing it.

Tags: android

Im new to android studio. I have an activity which is settings on turning on and off the music. When I turn of the music the image also changes to know that the music is turned off. but when i close the activity it goes back to the "playing music" image. How can I save the previous image or state of my activity after closing it. Do i need some save instance state something like that?  Here is my code

```
package com.example.mainmenu;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;


 public class settings extends AppCompatActivity {
 private ImageView close;
 private ImageView help;
 protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,         
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custompopup);


    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    final ImageView sound;
    close =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.txtclose);
    sound = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_sound);
    help = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_help);

    help.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent secondactivtyintent = new Intent(settings.this, 
    panuto1.class);
            startActivity(secondactivtyintent);

        }
    });
    help.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                    help.setImageResource(R.drawable.help);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                    help.setImageResource(R.drawable.help1);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            moveTaskToBack(false);
            finish();
        }
    });


    sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        private boolean fun = true;
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(fun)
            {
                sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.nosound);
                sound.setPressed(true);
                fun=false;
                stopService(new Intent(settings.this, 
   BackgroundSoundService.class));

                sound.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch(event.getAction())
                        {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                                sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.nosound1);
                                break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                                sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.nosound);
                                break;

                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                });

            }
            else
            {
                fun=true;
                sound.setPressed(true);
                sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound);
                startService(new Intent(settings.this, 
   BackgroundSoundService.class));
                sound.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch(event.getAction())
                        {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                                sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound1);
                                break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                                sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound);
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;

                    }

                });
            }

        }

    });

  }

 }
```

Comment: [NO "_Im new to_" please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: what kind of information do you want to keep the record of?

Comment: the image of the sound that serves as my button to turn off the background music sir. i want to keep the "button" on its previous state when i close it. this is what happens, when i turn off the music, the image will change to "turned off music". when i close the activity the image of the button turns back to "turned on music". how can i retain the last image of the button when i close it?

Comment: You can save anything as int, float, double or as String to SharedPreferences but this question should have been asked at least million times. Please search before asking.

Comment: I already search for it but i just don't know how to implement it. Im so sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SharedPreference` to save current state, update value in `SharedPreference` whenever you you change status.
When you get back from other activity get the status from `sharedPreference` and change you image.you can do this task in `onResume` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir.